# Static array declaration in php database class - incorrect syntax error?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm declaring a simple database class that includes an array of prepared statement, but for the life of me, I can't find the syntax error here.

```
class Database {
    private static $users_table = "users";
    private static $statements = array("username_available" => "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . self::$users_table . " WHERE Username='?'");
}
```

Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have quotes around the `?` for your parameter. Also, you cannot declare the `private static $statements` as an array.  Instead, you must initialize it in the constructor.

```
class Database {
    private static $users_table = "users";
    private static $statements;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->statements = array("username_available" => "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . self::$users_table . " WHERE Username='?'");
      // etc...
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using this class as a static class, so there won't be any instantiation. Should I just declare it in the function where it's used?

Comment: @pythonscript Yes, just create it in the function that will use it.

Comment: @pythonscript - Or just change `$statements` into a method that returns the array (see my answer), and use it w/ the command [`self::statements()`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NJsXO5)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot concatenate while assigning values on class variables declaration: you can assign just a scalar value or another array (or an object if I remember correctly).

You can assign expressions into a method, like the class constructor, or maybe another static method

```
class Database {
    private static $users_table = "users";
    private static $statements = null;
    public function __construct(){
        if(self::$statements === null){
            self::$statements = array("username_available" => "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . self::$users_table . " WHERE Username=?");
        }
    }
}
```

This code should work in your case. And as Michael said you should remove quotes around the question mark.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I think I'll be using isset, but the point is the same. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PHP likes declaring static class variables from concatenations or otherwise requires evaluation. You can't set a static variable to the result of a function call either:

```
private static $time = time(); # this will fail too. Value must be a literal value
```

In other words, a propety values in a class definition can't come from something that's evaluated.

So you have to hardcode the value of the `$users_table` string into the `$statements`:

```
private static $statements = array("username_available" => "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE Username=?");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're having problems due to requiring an evaluation when setting a class property.

This is because a PHP class property, [**"must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated."**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). See the examples on the previously linked page.

To keep the same format you could just have a static method, that simply returns the value you want:

```
<?php
class Database {
    private static $users_table = "users";
    private static function statements() {
           return array("username_available" => 
                 "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . self::$users_table . " WHERE Username=?");
    }
}
?>
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NJsXO5)